# Is it acceptable to give money I get from attending college to charity?

Tags: money, sadaqah

I receive money from college every week. I want to give this money to my chosen charity. Will this be acceptable? Because I have not earned it; I only get this money if I attend college.  So is this a certain typing of earning?

Comment: As long as you properly qualify for this income I personally don't see an issue with it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as soon as the money comes into your possession its yours. You can give it to charity organisations of your choice provided it is Muslim run.

Answer (score 0):

If this money is meant as stipend then yes, you can give it in charity to anyone, be it a trust or an individual.  You should distribute your charity among people based on their amount of need.